# How to configure UIDatePicker to only allow time selection within next 24 hours in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I have to configure the `UIDatePicker` to only allow time selection for the next 24 hours from current time.
This is how I set up the picker.

```
self.timePicker.minimumDate = Date()
self.timePicker.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour,
                                                    value: 24,
                                                    to: Date())
self.timePicker.datePickerMode = .time
```

But the time picker is not behaving correctly. If I select a time before the current time, it changes the date to tomorrow as it should. But then after that it does not let me select a time later than current time.

I am confused. Could anyone please help on this

Comment: I cannot reproduce the exact behaviour you described. It is 1:40 PM now, and I _can_ select 1:41 PM (unlike what you said). However, I cannot select 1:40 AM tomorrow because the date picker, when it's in `time` mode, only operates in a single day (the current day). How about use `dateAndTime` mode instead?

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say. If the date is important to you, this should be a dateAndTime picker. Otherwise your time loses its association with things like "now" and "24 hours from now".